# Strong password validation in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

It is not working in Laravel 10, How can I develop it in a proper way?

```
'password' => [
    'required|confirmed',
    Password::min(8)
        ->letters()
        ->mixedCase()
        ->numbers()
        ->symbols()
        ->uncompromised()
],
```

Trying strong password validation in Laravel 10 but it does not work. Hope an expert helps me to develop this.

Comment: Please share your expected and actual result.

Comment: afaik, the `->uncompromised()` needs `curl` to work as it require external services to see if the password is in the leak database or not. it needs internet.

Comment: Bagus Tesa
is it work in Laravel 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a expert but I can try helping you
Laravel Validation have alot of rules

```
    $request->validate([
    'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).+$',
]);
```

Explanation of this regex pattern:

`^` asserts the start of the line.
`(?=.*[a-z])` means there must be at least one lowercase letter.

`(?=.*[A-Z])` means there must be at least one uppercase letter.

`(?=.*\d)` means there must be at least one digit.

`(?=.*\W)` means there must be at least one special character (not a letter or digit).

`.+` matches any character (letters, digits, symbols) one or more times.

`$` asserts the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]+$/',
```

Comment: @Jeremy Caney,Marijus12 explained the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it.

you can create Laravel rules like this.

```
php artisan make:rule CustomPasswordRule
```

in the passes function you can write like this.

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).+$/',$value);
}
```

you can use your custom rule like this.

```
$request->validate([
    'password' => ['required', 'min:8', new CustomPasswordRule],
]);
```